# The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server error in ChangePassword Control

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I created an empty page with ChangePassword ASP.NET Control. 
This page doesn't have any codebehind. But When I use this control, it shows this error.

> The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL
>   Server. The connection will be closed.

This is my ASPX Page

```
<asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangePassword1" runat="server" 
     BackColor="#F5F7F9"  
     style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:150px;"
     BorderColor="#CCCC99" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
     Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="9pt" Height="281px" 
     onchangedpassword="ChangePassword1_ChangedPassword" Width="444px" 
     onchangingpassword="ChangePassword1_ChangingPassword" 
     oncontinuebuttonclick="ChangePassword1_ContinueButtonClick">
<CancelButtonStyle CssClass="button" Height="24px" Width="100px" />
<ChangePasswordButtonStyle CssClass="button" Height="24px" Width="150px" />
<ChangePasswordTemplate>
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" style="height:281px;width:444px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2" 
                            style="color:White;background-color:#8B9ACB;font-weight:bold;">
                            Change Your Password</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style= "height:20px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" width="180px"> 
                            <asp:Label ID="CurrentPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                                AssociatedControlID="CurrentPassword">Password:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="CurrentPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" 
                                Width="230px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CurrentPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="CurrentPassword" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="ChangePassword1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="NewPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                                AssociatedControlID="NewPassword">New Password:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="NewPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="230px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NewPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="NewPassword" ErrorMessage="New Password is required." 
                                ToolTip="New Password is required." ValidationGroup="ChangePassword1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="ConfirmNewPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                                AssociatedControlID="ConfirmNewPassword">Confirm New Password:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmNewPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" 
                                Width="230px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmNewPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="ConfirmNewPassword" 
                                ErrorMessage="Confirm New Password is required." 
                                ToolTip="Confirm New Password is required." ValidationGroup="ChangePassword1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2">
                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="NewPasswordCompare" runat="server" 
                                ControlToCompare="NewPassword" ControlToValidate="ConfirmNewPassword" 
                                Display="Dynamic" 
                                ErrorMessage="The Confirm New Password must match the New Password entry." 
                                ValidationGroup="ChangePassword1"></asp:CompareValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">

                        </td>
                        <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="ChangePasswordPushButton" runat="server" 
                                CommandName="ChangePassword" CssClass="button" Height="24px" 
                                Text="Change Password" ValidationGroup="ChangePassword1" Width="120px" />
                            <asp:Button ID="CancelPushButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                CommandName="Cancel" CssClass="button" Height="24px" Text="Cancel" style="margin-left:10px;"
                                Width="100px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ChangePasswordTemplate>
<TitleTextStyle BackColor="#8B9ACB" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

And, this is code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace IgnisAccess
{
    public partial class UserProfile : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ChangePassword1_ChangedPassword(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        protected void ChangePassword1_ChangingPassword(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ChangePassword1_ContinueButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your database connection string - it appears you're using a `UserInstance=true` in there somewhere.

This flag is supported *only* on SQL Server **Express** - so if you're using any other edition of SQL Server, you'll need to change that

Comment: my connection string is this::
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=SQL-01;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=MY_DB;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: @YesudassMoses: that's certainly not the one causing the problems ... what version of SQL Server are you connecting to? What's the output of `SELECT @@Version` ??

Comment: It results 
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: But I am not using any SQL Connection on the page right ??
and, every other page are working perfect

Comment: I would assume that the ASP.NET membership system that you use is probably referencing another connection string that uses the user instance flag ...

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 .

Comment: Check your web.config - does the ASP.NET membership system somehow reference another connection string in its configuration?

Comment: I am not using any ASP.NET Membership;

Comment: Well, search your entire solution for `User Instance=true` - somewhere, something is trying to use user instances which are *not* supported on the Developer edition

Comment: Yes, I did.... Nothing is there with name UserInstance. 
The other controls doesn't have any problem. Only the changePassword Control . So I am designing it manually now.